# Display all posts and sort them based on most viewed count

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to show most viewed posts using wordpress date_query:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); } else { $paged = 1; }
$date_query = [ ['after' => '1 day ago']];
$args = array(
'date_query' => $date_query,
'posts_per_page' => 30,
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', // I have the counter function and its working.
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'paged' => $paged,
'order' => 'DESC',
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $the_query;
```

The above code is showing most viewed posts published today only but I want to show all posts and display the most viewed posts today as primary.If there are no new posts I want to display automatically all most viewed posts instead.

Is there any different method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using sorting query, have a look at below code which will help you. Remove `date_query` this will restrict posts within given dates.

```
  $query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        ) 
    );
```

Comment: Sorry but if I remove date_query how can I show example most viewd posts in last day or last week how can I dedect that in this way?

Comment: So I have created some order options using php switch and I will add different dates thats why I asked this question if I do it in this way it will allways show the same.